# Vertically align text

Tags: vertical-alignment, pstricks, text

I know I can horizontally align text using the B argument like this:

```
\rput[B]{0}(-164,0){{\large\itshape{L}}}
```

But how do I vertically align it? Do I use the tabular command? Am I using the correct syntax?

```
\rput[B]{0}(-164,0){\begin{tabular}{c}{\large\itshape{L}}\end{tabular}}
```

Thanks.

[edit]

This seems to work:

```
\psTextFrame[linestyle=none,fillstyle=none](-156,-8)(-172,8){\large\itshape{L}}
```

But I read it is not a real pstricks object, so there might be other problems?

Comment: This is unclear. What do you mean by *horizontal* and *vertical* alignment when you only have a single item?

Comment: I mean vertical and horizontal centering with respect to the (x,y) coordinate.

Comment: Then use as optional argument for `\rput[C]` or nothing, it is the default.

Comment: The documentation I was reading doesn't mention the C argument. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PSTricks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what you mean with  "vertical" alignment. But `\rput` makes more
sense for words without line breaking. In the following example the two "L" are printed one over the other:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1pt}
\begin{pspicture*}(-250,-250)(200,200)
\psTextFrame[fillstyle=none](-156,-8)(-172,8){\large\itshape L} 
\rput(-164,0){\large\itshape L}\psdot(-164,0)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

By the way: `\itshape` is a switch! It has *no* argument.